# Can't block access to photos for iOS application - strange situation

Tags: ios, applications, photos, permission

I have an application to which I gave access to photos several years ago.

Now I want to prevent the application from accessing photos, but the application is missing in `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Photo`.
If I reinstall it, it immediately has access to the photos and does not ask for permission.

Updating to newest iOS 14.6 and resetting `Settings` -> `General` -> `Reset` -> `Reset Location and Privacy` doesn't help.

Comment: @fsb Probably yes, thanks. It's strange that Apple does not provide information about this, but makes the user worry))